# Add a color input and output to OSL shader

Tags: python, scripting, shaders, color

I'm trying to wrap my head around making shaders but I have no real coding experience. I've tried looking for a solution to my problem but I haven't found anything. Maybe I'm not phrasing it right? The problem is this:
I have a script that looks like this, which takes a texture with values in a certain range and then changes the range of the values while keeping their relative positions.

```
shader Exp_Shader(
    float tex = 0,
    float OldMax = 1,
    float OldMin = 0,
    float NewMax = 1,
    float NewMin = 0,
    output float Result = 0,
)
{
    Result = (((tex - OldMin)*(NewMax-NewMin))/(OldMax-OldMin)) + NewMin; 
}
```

The problem is, that this works on greyscale textures but not on color. How can I add a color input and output to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OSL, you can use color as type of parameter. For example see here your script. I changed the tex parameter and the Result parameter

```
shader Exp_Shader(
    color tex = 0,
    float OldMax = 1,
    float OldMin = 0,
    float NewMax = 1,
    float NewMin = 0,
    output color Result = 0,
)
{
    Result = (((tex - OldMin)*(NewMax-NewMin))/(OldMax-OldMin)) + NewMin; 
}
```

After doing this and pressing the refresh button the Script node will look like this:
[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks  for this! My problem was that I was trying to write it like : color tex = rgb(0,0,0)
I still need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@J.Bakker's answer is perfectly good .. but just for completeness..

There are a number of ways of constructing a `color` in OSL, including these examples given in the [Language Specification](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/src/doc/osl-languagespec.pdf):

```
color (0, 0, 0) // black
color ("rgb", .75, .5, .5) // pinkish
color ("hsv", .2, .5, .63) // specify in "hsv" space
color (0.5) // same as color (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

(see the rest of the `color` section for the complete list)